# Combined flair is updated in web browser and not in the Stack Exchange Android app

Tags: support, profile-page, android-app, combined-flair

Yesterday I got 200+ reputation on [GIS Stack Exchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/63592/arulkumar), the reputation is added in the combined flair in the web browsers, but the same is not updated in the Stack Exchange Android app.

In the [Network Profile flair](https://stackexchange.com/users/2855348/arulkumar?tab=flair) it is mentioned as

> please note that only sites where you have more than 200 reputation will appear, and that flair is only updated once every 24-36 hours.

If it is updated for web browsers and not for the Stack Exchange Android app, is it a bug or is there any extra time limit for the Stack Exchange Android app?

Adding the screenshots for reference:

**In the web browser**:

> [image: Web browser combined flair]

**In the Stack Exchange Android app**:

> [image: Stack Exchange Android app combined flair]

Stack Exchange Android App Version: **1.0.77**

Comment: I can see it now via the android app just fine. It is probably cached on your local device somehow, don't think it's a bug on SE side.

Comment: Yes, after manually deleted the `Cached data` I can see the latest update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is due to the cache.

Suggested by this [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273589/combined-flair-is-updated-in-web-browser-and-not-in-android-app?noredirect=1#comment889197_273589), after deleting my device *cached data*, I am able to see the latest flair update.

Cached data in the path: `Settings -> Storage -> Cached data`

Comment: Cheers! In two days you can also accept your own answer, to mark this officially as "resolved".