# "open in browser" redirects to SE app

Tags: support, android-app

When I click on the "open in browser" option, the question is just reloaded in a new site of the SE app. 
Where can you change the settings for this option (choose the application it is opened with).
Maybe I accidentally hit in the beginning open with SE-app, but I'm not even sure how it works.

Comment: Give a try with clearing your mobile's [Cached data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/273599/312043)

Comment: @Arulkumar I cleared the cache of stack exchange, that didn't work

Comment: @SomewhatMemorableName I don't know how I didn't find that...Anyway, the answer worked, thanks.